# How to properly manage all the checks passed from iOS UITest arguments in the project?

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, uitest

1, how to properly manage all the checks from the project arguments in the project? do we spam `isUITest` in project all over the places?

2, how to mock the iOS IAP receipt fresh result from UITest?

As you know the standard way of detecting UITest is through arguments. If we have more status like `isSubscribed`, `isLoggedIn`, etc that we will pass from arguments, how do we properly manage them, instead of if loops everywhere?

Comment: What do you mean by the standard way of detecting UITest?

Comment: @MikeTaverne I mean it's a common way to use launch environment or argument to pass in information, like `UITest` flags for the application to determine this is in UITest mode.